# SQL Server trigger on specific column updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID | CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME  |  NAME  | DESCRIPTION | LM_TIME
```

The `LM_TIME` column will be set automatically by a trigger when any of the other column values get updated.

However I want the `LM_TIME` .... **NOT** to get updated by the trigger when the `CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME` column is updated.

I am using the below trigger right now, which updates the `LM_TIME` when any of the column value is changed.

Simply I just want to make the trigger not to worry about `CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME` column. What modifications I have to make to achieve this effect?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateLM_TIME]
ON [dbo].[INSTITUTIONS]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE dbo.INSTITUTIONS
    SET lm_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120))
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
GO
```

Comment: If there's an `UPDATE` statement and it updates `CLINET_SYNCED_TIME` (and other columns) but happens to set it to the same value it already has, what should happen then?

Comment: It's not a problem sir.. I just want to make the trigger not to worry about "CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME" column

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768608/what-is-the-practical-use-of-timestamp-column-in-sql-server-with-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to Mr. Bhosale

```
USE [lms_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateLM_TIME]
ON [dbo].[INSTITUTIONS]

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

IF NOT UPDATE(CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME)

BEGIN

UPDATE dbo.INSTITUTIONS
SET lm_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120))
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)

END
```

Answer (score 9):

try this.

```
USE [lms_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateLM_TIME]
ON [dbo].[INSTITUTIONS]

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(ID) or UPDATE(NAME) or UPDATE(DESCRIPTION)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.INSTITUTIONS
        SET lm_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120))
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
    END
```

Or

```
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(CLIENT_SYNCED_TIME)
        PRINT 'Not Updated';
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.INSTITUTIONS
        SET lm_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 120))
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
        PRINT 'Updated';
    END
```

Comment: sir.. for simplicity I have specified only 4 columns but the table is actually  having more than 20 columns.! Is there any way to ignore only a specific column.!

Comment: sir thank u for the help... i've achived this by modifying your code IF NOT UPDATE(client_last_syncd_time)

Comment: @Pradeep also you can use if else for it. check code once

Comment: Wow..! Thanks sir..!

Comment: Where does the PRINT go, are you able to read it in logs?