# Inserting data in TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just created a new column `SCHEDULE` in a table `COURSE_OFFERING` with the data type `TIMESTAMP`.

While inserting data into the column (`WHERE` the primary key is `Course_ID`) I am using below code:

```
INSERT INTO COURSE_OFFERING ('SCHEUDLE')
VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP ('07-JAN-2019 07:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
WHERE COURSE_ID = '13477';
```

But SQL Server responded with an error

> Missing `SELECT` keyword

Can someone guide me where did I go wrong? or what should I use to insert data in timestamp column?

I am very new to the coding world, and is actually just learning, I would appreciate if you can keep it simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between datetime and timestamp in sqlserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105093/difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp-in-sqlserver)

Comment: The `timestamp` type is not user insertable, it is used for row versioning.  I think you need a `datetime` in your use case.

Comment: An `INSERT` statement **cannot** have a `WHERE` clause

Comment: And `TO_TIMESTAMP` is an Oracle function. I believe you've presented us with an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please have a look [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), then edit your question as needed.

Comment: Your query makes no sense at all.  Either database should get an error at the `where` and at the string where the column name should be.

Answer (score 0):

The question is clearly coming from an Oracle environment but this is how many people do it in SQL Server:

-- where t1 is of type  datetime2 and date is mm/dd/yyyy

```
INSERT INTO #X56 (T1)
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,'07/01/2019 07:00:00', 103)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can't do an INSERT with a WHERE clause.

Comment: @HardCode - um, yes you can, if you're using `INSERT ... SELECT ...`. I cannot think of anything off-hand that is restricted in that `SELECT`. There may be some edge cases but `WHERE` certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in INSERT ... SELECT, the WHERE is part of the SELECT, not the INSERT, to be technical. You cannot use `INSERT INTO foo (t1) VALUES ('bar') WHERE t2 = 123`, which was the point to ben's answer. Ben has since edited his answer.

Comment: The edit history only shows `SELECT` not `VALUES`. It's possible he managed to get an edit in in the grace period in which case I apologise that I couldn't see it there. But I'd thought the whole point of ben's answer was to switch from `VALUES` to `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

> or what should I use **to insert data in timestamp column**?

It seem to me that all he needs is `UPDATE`, as he wants to fill in only this column and only for already existing row (he was trying to use `WHERE` clause).

So the syntax should be this one:

```
update COURSE_OFFERING
set SCHEUDLE = '20190107 07:00:00'
where COURSE_ID = '13477';
```

But the problem is that he came here from the Oracle world (note `TO_TIMESTAMP`), so the column created has a wrong type. He wanted to add `datetime` column, but used `Oracle` data type that has another meaning in `SQL Server`.

So what he should do now is first drop the wrong column:

```
alter table COURSE_OFFERING drop column SCHEUDLE;
```

And then add the correct column:

```
alter table COURSE_OFFERING add SCHEUDLE datetime;
```

And only after these 2 steps do an `update`.