# SQL: Create pivot table to aggregate data by month and year from timestamp

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in my data set.

- email
- first name
- unsubscribe date (timestamp)

How can i create a pivot table in SQL to have years on the left in rows, and months in columns and count the number of people who unsubscribed by month and year?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.  [Timestamp is poorly named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105093/difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp-in-sqlserver), and has nothing to do with the time the person unsubscribed.